# Vue2Editor content not updated after axios data received

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous

I have a Vue component using [Vue2Editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-editor) which works very nice, but I'm getting an issue updating the content when I got data from an async function.

As a test I see text updated in a simple div.

**My async function code:**

```
async getPost(id) {
   this.content = "Here works"; // Update both content
   const {data} = await pressRepository.getPost(id)
   document.getElementsByClassName("ql-editor")[0].focus();
   this.content = data.article; // Update just the div content
}
```

**It works**

```
<div> {{content}}</div>
```

**It doesn't work**

```
<vue-editor v-model="content" :editorToolbar="customToolbar"></vue-editor>
```

**[EDIT]**

Fixed! commenting on the line:

```
//document.getElementsByClassName("ql-editor")[0].focus();
```

Comment: Has it something to do with the async loading of the data? Have you tried to debug with `<vue-editor v-if="content">`?

Comment: Thanks!  Just fixed removing the code  document.getElementsByClassName("ql-editor")[0].focus();  Don't know why...

Comment: Probably an error occurrs in this line and the next line is then not executed anymore. Don't use `document.getElementsByClassName` at all. Use the vue built-in `ref`, then you don't have such issues. Probably the element is not there at the time of the call and you are executing `focus()` on `undefined`.

Comment: it's strange. No errors in the console and the second box (the dive) it's updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
async getPost(id) {
   this.content = "Here works"; // Update both content
   const {data} = await pressRepository.getPost(id)
   document.getElementsByClassName("ql-editor")[0].focus();

   this.$nextTick(() => {
     this.content = data.article; // Update just the div content
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`this.$forceUpdate()`

Alos here is a working example:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <vue-editor v-model="body"/>
    <button @click="update">Update</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { VueEditor } from "vue2-editor";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    VueEditor
  },
  data() {
    return {
      body: `<b>Lost list↓↓↓</b>
    <ul>
       <li>a</li>
       <li>a</li>
       <li>a</li>
    </ul>
    <b>Lost list↑↑↑</b>`
    };
  },
  methods: {
    update() {
      this.body = 'Test texttttt ';
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed commenting the code

```
    //document.getElementsByClassName("ql-editor")[0].focus();
```

Don't know why this doesn't work with the async function.  But it fixed.